# Javascript to target a table that comes after an H1 containing specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to target a table only if it comes after an H1 containing 'Editing Shared Regions'

Here is the html showing the table I want to target:

```
<h1>Editing Shared Regions</h1>
<ul class="smartbar">
 <li class="selected"><a href="/core/apps/content/page/?id=-1">Regions</a></li>
</ul>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Items</th>
                            <th class="action"></th>
            <th class="action"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:contains()`, general sibling selector `~`

```js
 $("h1:contains('Editing Shared Regions') ~ table")
.css("color", "blue")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Editing Shared Regions</h1>
<ul class="smartbar">
  <li class="selected"><a href="/core/apps/content/page/?id=-1">Regions</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Region</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Items</th>
      <th class="action"></th>
      <th class="action"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That is awesome, thanks so much! So the ~ selector means 'siblings'. Brilliant.

Comment: @Sly See [General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) _"The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent."_

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that doesn't use jQuery. I shouldn't extend the DOM but it makes it fun to write a one-liner like guest271314's example.

```js
NodeList.prototype.contains = function(searchText) {
  for (var ix = 0; ix < this.length; ix++) {
    if (this.item(ix).innerText.trim() === searchText) {
      return this.item(ix);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

Node.prototype.findNext = function(tag) {
  var el = this;
  while (el.nextSibling) {
    el = el.nextSibling;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === tag.toUpperCase()) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

document.querySelectorAll('h1').contains('Editing Shared Regions').findNext('table').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>A Heading</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>This is not the table you're looking for</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <h1>Editing Shared Regions</h1>
        <ul class="smartbar">
            <li class="selected"><a href="/core/apps/content/page/?id=-1">Regions</a></li>
        </ul>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Region</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Items</th>
                    <th class="action"></th>
                    <th class="action"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>PNW</td>
                    <td>Land</td>
                    <td>meow</td>
                    <td>x</td>
                    <td>y</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Like it Will. It's interesting to see written in the the 'base' JS that JQuery works from. Look at the size of that thing.